# Is players adversarial focus RPG even possible to execute?

Tags: gm-techniques, game-design

I am new to the RPG community, when I am thinking of a adversarial relationship, I generally think of players co-operate to fight against GM controlled mobs in a campaign.

But talking about game focus on player vs player, is there a way to handle information between different parties in a smooth and private manner?

By private I mean:

1. location of each players is only known by their teammate, unless direct encounter of the enemies
2. Some decisions made by each players is only share among the same parties (it is clear that when you are not directly encounter with your enemies, you would like to make some preparation say ambush and setting up trap, which you certainly  don't want your enemies know what is waiting ahead of them)
3. The items, abilities and equipment possess by each player (The uncertainty between each players add flavour to the battle, which simulate a real battle)

By smooth I mean:

1. Since each player don't have access to other information, the GM should do his job to verify the truth (user couldn't lie about their action during encounter, they could not make up a move or use a spell their characters don't possess. However while not combat they could bluff about anything)
2. When dealing with different parties, as the actions and interaction of between that parties should keep secret/private to the opposing party, GM may force to only interacting with that party causing the other party IDLE.
3. Due to (1) and (2) of the situation, the concurrence and the smoothness of the game are being affected. The two parties may not able to parallel engage with the GM, causing issue of fairness, information synchronisation and interactiveness.

So my question is: Is there a method for the GM to mitigate problem of smoothness, while preserving the adversarial elements and privacy.

What I could think of is perhaps introduce more than one GM to deal with different parties, but still it is quite difficult to sync the action across parties.

p.s. since I am new to the community (I just watch some games played on the youtube say CoC and DnD etc. where I don't have the full picture of the game system and rules) Maybe there already exist rules and system in now market available Trpg which I don't know, a guide or portal point to existing material would be appreciated too.

Comment: Are you interested in play online or in person?

Comment: Hi C. Calvert, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] when you get and chance and visit the [help] or ask here in the comments for more information (use @ to ping someone). As written this question is extremely broad and possibly a shopping question which are off topic here. As you are new to the hobby you likely don't understand the scope of a question like this. Are you looking for game systems in which this is possible? Or advice for how to implement it a D&D like system? Try to narrow down your question to identify exactly what you are looking for. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: FYI: There exist many player-vs-player RPGs. Many are even GMless, such as Firebrands. I recommend googling around and doing some research on what exists. When you reach 15 rep, you'd be welcome to talk with us in [general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) about it.

Comment: I think it is possible, in a game I played, there was a cursed magic sword that communicated only to one player. The GM txt messaged me directly the things the cursed sword was saying. It worked well at the table for secret communications. These days everyone has a smartphone, could set up a backchannel for private comms using whats app or fb messenger.

Answer (score 0):

## The basic rules cover this situation without any problems

The [core game loop of D&D](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#HowtoPlay) is:

> 1. The DM describes the environment.
> 2. The players describe what they want to do.
> 3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’ actions.

There is never any need for players to communicate directly. The DM is effectively a buffer between the players. When playing D&D it isn't uncommon to have a player say something in secret directly to the DM. This doesn't cause any problems.

This can be used for PvP too. For example imagine a PvP between Players 1 and 2. If played online the DM may have a private chat with each player, and a group chat too:

> Player 1 to DM: I shout "you are dog meat bad guy!" at the enemy Fighter and then cast fireball at them!
>
> DM to all: Player 1 shouts "you are dog meat bad guy!" at you, then they thrust their staff forward and you see a burning orb start to form
>
> Player 2 to DM: oh heck, too bad I can't counterspell that
>
> DM to Player 1: Roll some die!
>
> *Player 1 rolls dice*
>
> DM resolves damage
>
> DM to both players: Player 1 erupts in flames and takes 18 damage

In real life this is no trickier to achieve than a normal team based game. Each team will huddle together and discuss their tactics, then relay their turn to the DM.

D&D is not typically played with a map unless there is combat or position is important on granular level so the question of hiding movement isn't too concerning. Worst case the DM has their own map to track everyone's movement, and teams have their own copy to track their own. DMs already often have their own map to track hidden enemies and statuses, as well as copies of each player's character sheet.

When talking about smoothness, you should understand that in a typical D&D game you are taking turns, so players are used to having times where they aren't doing much. Often they use this time to plan their next move, observe what is going on, check their phone, eat a snack, chat with others (quietly) who are also not taking a turn.

Comment: The question didn’t specify D&D or its 5th edition.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes